# Login from Mobile Phone

Tags: login, mobile

I use the "Member Access" Plugin to restrict the content of my Blog to registered users only. This works from a PC with no problem.

But if I want to login from my Android Phone the login page always displays no matter if I input correct credentials or not. I don't get logged in.

I deactivated all other plugins and used the TwentyEleven Theme.

How can I login from a mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to allow Cookies in my Android Phone Web Browser. After activating Cookies I could log in my Blog and got redirected to its main page.